# Проблема с запуском .py через virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

Структура моего проекта вот такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запуска через консоль о выдаёт ошибку:

```
(venv) alex@alex-YOGA11S:~/Documents/PythonProjects/APrint$ python3 tests/tests.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/tests.py", line 3, in <module>
    from Classes.Scanner import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Classes'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Оно то и понятно, т.к. в папке тестов нет папки классов.
Но если запускать файл через PyCharm то все работает, и ошибки не выдаёт (в качестве интепритатора выбрано именно это venv).

Пробывал в sys.path добавить путь к директории проекта. Все заработало, однако сгенерированные qr коды - результат работы программы помещаются в папку проекта, а не в папку tests. При запуске через PyCharm все работает нормально, сохраняет куда нужно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Коды сохраняются при помощи

```
qr.save("qr({i}).jpg") #QR - PIL image class obj.
```

Comment: Хорошо проиллюстрирована структура проекта :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю , что в pycharm в переменных среды просто указан APrint. Как вариант в тест можешь через sys.path добавить путь до APrint, после этого импортировать classes

Comment: Попробывал, но тогда возникает проблема с сохранением результата (подробнее в вопросе)